# lexical and syntax analizer on android?

Tags: android, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I was wondering. Is there any lexical/syntax analizer (like Flex/Bison) that would work on Android? In this case it would be something like JavaCC, considering the Android SDK uses Java.

So far I have only found out that ANTLR could work on Android. Are there any other options you know of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Java ports for both Flex and Bison but I suppose both Flex & Bison can be compiled for android. Android is not only Java, you can use C, too. See Android NDK for more information.

Comment: I am aware of the Java ports, but would they work with the Android SDK? I'm just looking for any possible testimony/help since I can't happen to find any information on the internet so far. Also, thanks about the Android NDK information, but I would really try to avoid Android NDK since I am not an experienced Android developer.

Comment: They should work without problems on Android. They don't use any UI frameworks, only basic APIs. The best thing you can do is try it :)